# jQuery move left

Tags: jquery, html, css, move

I'm trying to add a small nice effect to a submenu but I can't use `marginLeft` because it will mess up a bit the container. So I'm trying to it by using `left` instead of `marginLeft`, but I can't get it to work... any ideas why?

```
$('#order_list li').hover(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ "left": "14px" }, 250, function() {
    $(this).animate({ "left": "10px" }, 250);
  });
},function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ "left": "4px" }, 250, function() {
    $(this).animate({ "left": "0px" }, 250);
  });
});
```

Comment: your effect is to move the 'li' to the left after some event is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CSS Left](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp) only works on [positioned](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) elements.

Try adding `position:relative;` to the `li`.

e.g.

```
#order_list li {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#order_list li').hover(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ "textIndent": "14px" }, 250, function() {
    $(this).animate({ "textIndent": "10px" }, 250);
  });
},function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ "left": "4px" }, 250, function() {
    $(this).animate({ "textIndent": "0px" }, 250);
  });
});
```